# How can you delay object creation until you have read in all parameters?

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to solve a problem with creating a custom object with multiple parameters, but the parameters have to first be found one by one using a `Scanner`.

So basically, given an input file, where each line will represent a new object with multiple attributes (a county with its name, its crime index, etc.), I am using a `Scanner` with a while loop to scan the input file line by line, and then within that loop I'm using another while loop and a new `Scanner` that then scans each word within the line. That way, I can separate all of the object-to-be's attributes and then create the object by passing all of those values into the constructor.

What I can't figure out is how to delay the creation of the object until I have every word in each line, since every line in the input file is to be made into an object, with every word in that line being used as a parameter for the object.

Does anyone know how this can be done effectively without having to store all the words into an array or something like that?

Here's the constructor from the object class that will take all of the words of a line, which are all in proper order, and create a new object for each line in the input file:

```
public CountyItem(String countyName, String countyState, double countyPercentageClintonVoters, double countyResidentMedianAge,
            int countyResidentMeanSavings, int countyPerCapitaIncome, double countyPercentageBelowPovertyLevel,
            double countyPercentageVeterans, double countyPercentageFemale, double countyPopulationDensity, 
            double countyPercentageLivingInNursingHomes, int countyCrimeIndexPerCapita){

        itemCountyName = countyName;
        itemCountyState = countyState;
        itemCountyPercentageClintonVoters = countyPercentageClintonVoters;
        itemCountyResidentMedianAge = countyResidentMedianAge;
        itemCountyResidentMeanSavings = countyResidentMeanSavings;
        itemCountyPerCapitaIncome = countyPerCapitaIncome;
        itemCountyPercentageBelowPovertyLevel = countyPercentageBelowPovertyLevel;
        itemCountyPercentageVeterans = countyPercentageVeterans;
        itemCountyPercentageFemale = countyPercentageFemale;
        itemCountyPopulationDensity = countyPopulationDensity;
        itemCountyPercentageLivingInNursingHomes = countyPercentageLivingInNursingHomes;
        itemCountyCrimeIndexPerCapita = countyCrimeIndexPerCapita;
    }
```

And here's my program's main method (still unfinished of course) that shows what I'm talking about with my plan to use nested while loops and two separate scanners to first read every line in the input file and then every word in that line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        //Scanner and FileWriter
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("data/test1.txt"));  //change this to use different test .txt file
        FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("data/output.txt");

        //loops through each line in inputl.txt until end is reached
        while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

            //loops through every word in a given line
            while(lineScanner.hasNext()){

            }
            lineScanner.close();
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Refer to the Builder Pattern - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.html

Comment: The CountyItems that you create can and should be immutable.  For this reason, and because you have so many parameters, a recommended approach to this problem is to use the Builder Pattern.  Using a builder, the object is not instantiated until all the data for your object can be assembled.

Comment: Whenever you have *many* method/constructor parameters, you should look to improve your design, either by using the builder pattern, or by factoring "related" parameters into classes, which you then compose into the top-level `CountyItem`.

Comment: You could just have your constructor throw an exception if it didn't find everything it needed in the file.

Comment: This is not a forum, it's a site built for Q&A. You don't need to put your tags or "solved" in the title, and you shouldn't. Accept an answer if one answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builder pattern to slowly build up your constructor's dependencies, or you could also just introduce another constructor that takes in a `File`, and you can move all the logic from your main method into that constructor.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!? That builder pattern is exactly what will help me! Thank you!

Comment: @MattMc Anytime